# Requested an insecure image error with blogger

Tags: blogger

I have a script that list posts from blogger blog feed API, I have a problem with fetching https images from feed.

Developers console logging some warnings for none secured image links, How to get ride of this problem ?

[image]

Here is my code snippet:

```js
function saringtags(r, l) {
  for (var e = r.split("<"), n = 0; n < e.length; n++) - 1 != e[n].indexOf(">") && (e[n] = e[n].substring(e[n].indexOf(">") + 1, e[n].length));
  return e = e.join(""), e = e.substring(0, l - 1)
}

function relpostimgcuplik(r) {
  for (var l = 0; l < r.feed.entry.length; l++) {
    var e = r.feed.entry[l];
    reljudul[relnojudul] = e.title.$t, 
      postcontent = "", 
      "content" in e ? postcontent = e.content.$t : "summary" in e && (postcontent = e.summary.$t), 
      relcuplikan[relnojudul] = saringtags(postcontent, numchars), 
      "media$thumbnail" in e ? postimg = e.media$thumbnail.url : postimg = "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.GIF", 
      relgambar[relnojudul] = postimg;

    for (var n = 0; n < e.link.length; n++){
      if ("alternate" == e.link[n].rel) {
        relurls[relnojudul] = e.link[n].href;
        break
      } 
      relnojudul++
    }
  }
}

function contains(r, l) {
  for (var e = 0; e < r.length; e++)
    if (r[e] == l) return !0;
  return !1
}

function artikelterkait() {
  for (var r = new Array(0), l = new Array(0), e = new Array(0), n = new Array(0), t = 0; t < relurls.length; t++) contains(r, relurls[t]) || (r.length += 1, r[r.length - 1] = relurls[t], l.length += 1, l[l.length - 1] = reljudul[t], e.length += 1, e[e.length - 1] = relcuplikan[t], n.length += 1, n[n.length - 1] = relgambar[t]);
  reljudul = l, relurls = r, relcuplikan = e, relgambar = n;
  for (var t = 0; t < reljudul.length; t++) {
    var a = Math.floor((reljudul.length - 1) * Math.random()),
        u = reljudul[t],
        i = relurls[t],
        o = relcuplikan[t],
        s = relgambar[t];
    reljudul[t] = reljudul[a], relurls[t] = relurls[a], relcuplikan[t] = relcuplikan[a], relgambar[t] = relgambar[a], reljudul[a] = u, relurls[a] = i, relcuplikan[a] = o, relgambar[a] = s
  }
  for (var g, m = 0, d = Math.floor((reljudul.length - 1) * Math.random()), c = d, h = document.URL; relmaxtampil > m && (relurls[d] == h || (g = "<li class='news-title clearfix'>", g += "<a href='" + relurls[d] + "' rel='nofollow' target='_top' title='" + reljudul[d] + "'><div class='overlayb'><img src='" + relgambar[d] + "' /></div></a>", g += "<div class='overlaytext'><a class='relinkjdulx' href='" + relurls[d] + "' target='_top'>" + reljudul[d] + "</a></div>", g += "<span class='news-text'>" + relcuplikan[d] + "</span>", g += "</li>", document.write(g), m++, m != relmaxtampil)) && (d < reljudul.length - 1 ? d++ : d = 0, d != c););
}
var relnojudul    = 0,
    relmaxtampil  = 6,
    numchars      = 90,
    reljudul      = new Array,
    relurls       = new Array,
    relcuplikan   = new Array,
    relgambar     = new Array;
```

Answer (score 0):

In function `relpostimgcuplik` you get image path from `e.media$thumbnail.url`, so you can replace the start of path (`http://` or `//`) with `https://`, using `replace` function:

```js
postimg = e.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/^http:\/\/|^\/\//, 'https://')
```